# transparent glass material refract the light

Tags: glass

I am trying to create a transparent glass for my windows. But somehow, I found out the glass is creating a refraction. My furniture is now refracted.
This how its look with windows and glass :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SRTv.jpg

and this how its look without windows :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qvuD.jpg

this is my glass formula :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5LUS.jpg

Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Glass refracts light, this is what it usually does so there's nothing wrong about it. I don't know why you setup your glass like that, although a lot of people do it.

Most of the time I simply use a *Glass BSDF* with an IOR of 1.45 or a *Principled BSDF* with *Transmission* set to 1.

This should work if you use it correctly: do your windows have a thickness or are they just flat planes? Real windows have a thickness, if you have flat planes the refraction works as if your furniture was embedded inside a glass cube.

The setup you have there is mostly used by people because of balck artifacts they experience when using simple glass. To avoid this, go to the *Render Properties* > *Light Paths* > *Max Bounces* and set a high value for *Transparent* like 64 or more.

On your windows this shouldn't matter, but sometimes with more complex glass objects there are still dark parts that are unwanted. In this case you have to increase the max bounces for *Glossy*. To have an effect, the *Total* bounces have to increased to this value as well (this is not necessary for the *Transparency* bounces).

The last problem is, which might be another reason for your setup, that the glass still absorbs a lot of light and your room looks quite dark from the outside. Then of course you have to mix in a *Transparency BSDF* node to make the glass transparent or invisible for certain rays. Although in reality it is like that - sun and sky are really really bright light sources, so standing outside and taking a picture without over-exposure results in dark windows. Or if you want to see what's inside, the outside gets very very bright.

I'm sorry, that was quite a long answer to say: the strange refraction might come from simple planes as windows. But I can't tell from your screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like due to double glass window. I create the window using Archimesh add on, and it create front and back glass window by default. Everything looks what it should after i remove the back glass.

[image: Final Render]

Edit : I think I found the real culprit. The wrong refraction is due to unwrap and Smart UV project. The solution is don't unwrap the glass faces.

Comment: I don't know the Archimesh addon, I don't use it. But usually, as I described in my answer, two "layers" of glass would be correct to avoid refractions - in case they are facing in the right direction... the outside glass plane has to be facing outwards with its normal, the inside plane has to be facing inwards. If they are both facing in the same direction or opposite to how they should, this makes problems. I guess now that you've deleted one plane, the one you're looking through has its normal pointing inwards. This looks okay if you're looking in, but looking out will look wrong.